# Yii2 get data using hasMany relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a query `$occupier` that get all the ID (10 & 16) from the table. The problem is how should I put it in the activeDataProvider query so that I can get all the ID that pass on since I cant do foreach loop inside the query.

Relation:

```
public function getop_occupier()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OpOccupier::classname(),['id'=>'unit_id']);
    }
```

Controller:

```
$occupier = OpOccupier::find()
                ->where(['unit_id'=>$id])
                ->all();


$dataProviderTranscation = new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => OpOccupierTrxGroup::find()->where(['or','occupier_id'=>10,'occupier_id'=>16]),]);
```

I tried:

```
$dataProviderTranscation = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => OpOccupierTrxGroup::find()->where(['occupier_id'=>$occupier['id'])->all();
```

It return error UNDEFINED INDEX ID.

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Remove `all()`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use to lefJoin relation for joining table

```
$dataProviderTranscation = 
 new ActiveDataProvider([
'query' => 
      OpOccupierTrxGroup::find()
       ->where(['op_occupier'=>$occupier['id'])
       ->andWhere(['occupier.id'=>[10,16]])
       ->leftJoin('occupier','occupier.id=op_occupier_trx_group.occupier_id')
       ->all();
```